# How do you fit an image in react native?

Tags: react-native

// How do you set the image on the top of the screen without losing the aspect ration?

```
[![import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    export default class DisplayAnImageWithStyle extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Image
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={{flex:1}}
              source={{uri: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ba/84/1c/ba841cc07934b508458a7faea62141a8.jpg'}}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    // Skip these lines if you are using Create React Native App.
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(
      'DisplayAnImageWithStyle',
      () => DisplayAnImageWithStyle
    );][1]][1]
```

// Here the liked image shows that it is not fitting well... it is not showing from the top... do you have any idea how I can set the image without any padding?
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYNKn.png

Comment: What do you mean 'how to set the image on the top of screen without losing aspect ration'? top aligned?

Comment: yes top alignment, when  i set resizeMode="contain", it places the image in the center, but i want to align it on the top..please any idea ?

Comment: I am not sure if adding `style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}` to Image help.

Answer (score 0):

So you might wanna use `resizeMode: 'cover'` with a height and width.

```
<Image
  resizeMode="contain"
  style={{ width: 200, height:220, resizeMode: 'cover'}}
  source={{uri: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ba/84/1c/ba841cc07934b508458a7faea62141a8.jpg'}}
 />
```

Here's an example https://snack.expo.io/HJTFg9tU4

Let me know if this works for you.